# Eclipse Upgrade Not Working

Tags: android, eclipse, nullpointerexception

My Eclipse out of the blue stopped building my Android so I removed the old version and have installed Indigo.  When I try to import an Android project in I get this error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project 'ACCUWX_HoneyComb'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Android Pre Compiler' on project 'ACCUWX_HoneyComb'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
Errors running builder 'Java Builder' on project 'ACCUWX_HoneyComb'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Please help!

Comment: have you installed the Android SDK and stuff in your new Eclipse?

Comment: Installed some, now installing other versions to see if that corrects.

Comment: Make sure eclipse is building using java 1.6. It will default to 1.7 if you have it installed

Comment: I have no idea what is going on...I have installed all Android SDK's from 4.0.3 down to 1.6 including extras.  I try to start eclipse and I get this:  "An internal error occurred during "Initializing Java Tooling"   AND Android SDK Content Loader "parseSdkContent failed...java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Eclipse is building using java 1.6.  Still same error

Comment: I had unmerged files in project so I reverted back to HEAD with git, imported project and it worked.  I am now going to attempt the merge because that is where all went wrong yesterday and caused me to upgrade my eclipse.

Comment: Eclipse didn't include my "src" folder in the project and I use this project as a shared project.  Therefore when I was trying to run my other project, it didn't have any necessary files with the jar.

Answer (score 18):

Try removing the .metadata folder from your workspace.  This holds all your configurations, even after a new install.  I think if you just delete this folder, assuming everything is in place, you should be up and running again.

Comment: +1  
the ULTIMATE SOLUTION, lol, I tried everything except this, and wow this works...HAIL @jjNford.

Comment: well, this effectively removed my workspace :) so be **warned**, fellow naive developers! and do **rename** instead of *delete*

Comment: @naxa i think this is straight forward given you are removing a hidden folder full of configurations from your workspace - as mentioned above.

Comment: I like the answer, still it's maybe best to keep things with (kind of) data loss included being told explicitly. Telling it directly is better than leaving it hang in the indirect. Especially when the spirit of NullPointerException, and reminiscence of null pointer dereference, shadows us all from the skies! ;)

Answer (score 6):

The 21.0.1 version of the Eclipse ADT tools has a bug that prevents a project building if you have any files without extensions in them. This is a particular problem for users (like me) using subversion which has extenion-less files.

The solution is to install the 21.1 *preview* version of the ADT tools and SDK manager from Google. Clear instructions can be [found here](http://tools.android.com/preview-channel) and you can read all the background add your voice to the [angry mob of developers here](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42051).

Comment: This solved it for me, I am getting more and more frustrated with android development.

Answer (score 5):

This happened to me today with ADT v21.0.1-543035 and it turned out to be the .svn directories throughout the directory structure.  See http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=42051

Worked around the issue by upgrading svn client and working copy to 1.7.

Comment: +1 big thanks, after going from 1.6.x to 1.7.x i had to 'upgrade working copy' and then delete and re-add the project.

Answer (score 4):

For me, the source of the `NullPointerException` problem was a host-side Junit test project that references (and tests) code from an Android project.  It didn't have a `project.properties` file.  It's not an Android project, but for some reason the newer version of the SDK somehow expects the file there.  To fix the problem, I just copied a `project.properties` file from an Android project to the host unit test project.

Answer (score 3):

I had something similar. The problem was created by having some files without extension inside the /src folder.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, a branch tool, changed the encode of the file project.properties, I changed the encode to Windows-1265 and the problem was solved.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue and fixed it by following comment number 6 in this page:
[Issue 42051: Subversion folder causes NPE in PreCompilerBuilder](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?can=2&start=0&num=100&q=&colspec=ID%20Type%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20Stars&groupby=&sort=&id=42051)

Let me quote the comment:

> Solved it by installing subversion support packages for eclipse:
>
> http://gan.so/VgYT
>
> It's still a bug but...

Answer (score 1):

same problem here, I closed Eclipse, manually removed any files in folder gen for the project, started Eclipse again, and made a build.

Answer (score 1):

For also me, the source of the NullPointerException problem was a host-side Junit test project that references (and tests) code from an Android project. It didn't have a project.properties file. I added it and problem got fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution on this website(https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=68755)

So basically, what we should do is :
    Bring up $ADT_DIR/eclipse/Eclipse.app/Contents/MacOS/eclipse.ini in an editor.  Before the -vmargs line, insert these two lines:

```
-vm 
/System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions/1.6/Commands/java
```

you can find the eclipse.ini following this
    (On a Mac OS X system, you can find eclipse.ini by right-clicking (or Ctrl+click) on the Eclipse executable in Finder, choose Show Package Contents, and then locate eclipse.ini in the MacOS folder under Contents)

Answer (score -1):

Upgrades did not work for me (on Linux), so I just installed **IntelliJ Idea** (build 123.155). Had to modify idea.sh to set `JDK_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.7.0` (the Oracle JDK) and to select *[menu]* -- *Run* -- *Run...* -- *Edit Configurations...* -- *Target Device* -- *USB device* to make it work with the real device.