# Error occurred during the build

Tags: java, android, eclipse, build, nullpointerexception

When I am importing a project into eclipse, I get this error:

```
Errors occurred during the build.
Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project     
'android.app.NativeActivity'.
java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Does anybody know how to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue is predominantly caused by issues with the `project.properties` file. This post should help you resolve the issue:[Mac Error Create Android Project - "Errors running builder 'Android Resource Manager' on project"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18096315/mac-error-create-android-project-errors-running-builder-android-resource-man)